# how to pass multiple classNames to inner children with emotion js

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I want to split the components into baseUI one and styled one:

eg.
MyComponent.jsx

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  ...
  render() {
    const { wrapperClassName, className, childClassName } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={wrapperClassName>
        <div className={className />
        <div className={childClassName} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

StyledMyComponent.jsx

```
import styled from 'react-emotion'

const StyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)(
  ...
  ...
)

export default StyledMyComponent
```

however anything I put to the styled function's argument they will go to the className only, is there a way I specify which props goes to which className?

also can I do something like sass/less with children selector?
hypothetically something like this:

```
const classes = css`
  color: red;
  span { // this works
    color: black;
  }
  .childClassName { // this doesn't work
    color: green;
  }

`
<MyComponent className={classes} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

What you can do, is create specific components for the underlying div. This is how I make my components:

```
const MyComponentStyle = styled('div')....;
const MySecondComponentStyle = styled('div')...;
const MyThirdStyle = styled('div')...;

const MyComponent = ({ wrapperClassName, childClassName, className }) =>
      <MyComponentStyle className={wrapperClassName}>
        <MySecondComponentStyle className={className} />
        <MyThirdStyle className={childClassName} />
      </MyComponentStyle>
    )
  }
}
```

### Conditionally styling the element and its children based on class names

You can conditionally change the styling of stuff below the *main component* based on its classes.

Taking your example:

```
const Something = () => (
  <MyComponent className={classes}>
    <div className="childClassName">child</div>
    <div className="otherChildClassName">child</div>
  </MyComponent>
```

You can style the children like so:

```
const classes = css`
  color: red;
  span {
    color: black;
  }
  & .childClassName {
    color: green;
  }
`
```

note the `&` character. It essentially means "this class". So `& .childClassName` means "childrens of this element with class `childClassName`.

You could also use `&.someClassName` (note the lack of space), which would mean: "this element when it also has a class named `someClassName`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have updated a little the question, is there something like second approach possible?